# Why Toast in this application does not show anything?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I wrote an application that connect to wamp server ( with a MySQl datatbase that one of its rows in table users have Username="pooriya" and Password="123")
This application checks if Username "pooriya" exist then Toast the password and if does not exist Toast "no user"

When i run this app on emulator , it should Toast "123", but 
empty Toast is shown . Why ?
Even when i change the User to a not existing Username , like "poori" , again empty Toast is shown . Why ?
database name is "note_test_2_db"
And when i enter the address "http://127.0.0.1:8080/mysite1/index.php" in my browser , it shows "no user" , then i guess that the php file works correctly and the problem is in my android code .
Thanks

```
package com.example.GetDataFromServer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    public static String res = "";
    Button btn;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        new getdata("http://127.0.0.1:8080/mysite1/index.php", "pooriya").execute();

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
}




package com.example.GetDataFromServer;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: Farid
 * Date: 3/15/19
 * Time: 4:09 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class getdata extends AsyncTask {
    private String Link = "";
    private String User = "";

    public getdata(String link, String user) {
        Link = link;
        User = user;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... objects) {
        try {
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(User, "UTF8");

            URL mylink  = new URL(Link);
            URLConnection connect = mylink.openConnection();

            connect.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr= new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            MyActivity.res = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        return "";  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

```
     $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("note_test_2_db",$con);
        $user=$_POST['username'];
        $sqlQ="select * from users where Username='$user'";
        $result= mysql_Query($sqlQ);
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        if($row[0]){
            print $row[1];
        }
        else{
            print "no user";
        }
        mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: Have you added internet permission to your manifest file ?

Comment: Check it like this and let me know if it doesn't works `Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Hello this is toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:8080` is not the IP address you need to use. 127.0.0.1 is the address of the emulator itself. Also you are ignorring the exception, that's why you don't know that something is wrong.

Comment: NEVER, NEVER, NEVER trust user input! The line `$user=$_POST['username'];` could be used for perform a SQLInjection! Escape the data with  `mysql_real_escape_string` or use `PDO`

Comment: your toast message is empty. What do you want to show user if the message is empty???

Comment: @RahulKhurana , the idea is that the toast message should not be empty

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** It seems your code to show `Toast` is incorrect.

```
new getdata("http://127.0.0.1:8080/mysite1/index.php", "pooriya").execute();

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

When the first line is executed, the app will start the `AsyncTask` which connects to your server to get the response (`"123"` or `"No User"`).

If you click on the button `btn` before the `AsyncTask` completed, at this time, the value of `res` is `""`, that why you always get empty `Toast`.

**Solution:** You can do the following steps

**Step 1:** Because `getdata` is a separate class, so you need to define an interface to pass data (`"123"` or `"No User"` or any value) back to `MyActivity`.

```
public interface OnDataListener {
    void onData(String result);
}
```

**Step 2:** Modify `getdata` class

```
public class getdata extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {
    private String Link = "";
    private String User = "";
    private WeakReference<OnDataListener> mListener;

    public getdata(String link, String user, OnDataListener listener) {
        Link = link;
        User = user;
        mListener = new WeakReference<>(listener);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... objects) {
        try {
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(User, "UTF8");

            URL mylink = new URL(Link);
            URLConnection connect = mylink.openConnection();

            connect.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            // This string will pass as param of onPostExecute method.
            return sb.toString(); // Will return "123" or "No User" if there is no exception occurs.
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        // If your app reach this line, it means there is an exception occurs, using a unique string for debugging.
        // This string will pass as param of onPostExecute method
        return "An exception has been caught!!!";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        // Pass the result back to MyActivity's onData method.
        if (mListener != null && mListener.get() != null) {
            mListener.get().onData(result);
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** Let `MyActivity` implements `OnDataListener` interface.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnDataListener {

    public static String res = "";
    Button btn;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        new getdata("http://127.0.0.1:8080/mysite1/index.php", "pooriya", this).execute();

        // TODO: Comment-out this code
//        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//            }
//        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onData(String result) {
        // result is passed from the AsyncTask's onPostExecute method.
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**Note:** Because you do not use any loading indicator while connecting to the server, so you need to wait a few seconds to see the Toast on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem . I should use

> http://10.0.2.2:8080/mysite1/index.php

instead

> http://127.0.0.1:8080/mysite1/index.php